# String Concatenation / Overwriting?

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

This is a program that reads in a CSV file, adds the values to a dictionary class and then analyses a string in a textbox to see if any of the words match the dictionary entry. It will replace abbreviations (LOL, ROFL etc) into their real words. It matches strings by splitting the inputted text into individual words.

```
 public void btnanalyze_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var abbrev = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Jordan Moffat/Desktop/coursework/textwords0.csv"))
        {
            string line;
            string[] row;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                row = line.Split(',');

                abbrev.Add(row[0], row[1]);
                Console.WriteLine(abbrev);
            }
        }


        string twitterinput;
        twitterinput = "";
        // string output;
        twitterinput = txtInput.Text;
        {
            char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };

            string text = twitterinput;

            string[] words = twitterinput.Split(delimiterChars);


         string merge;
            foreach (string s in words)
            {
                if (abbrev.ContainsKey(s))
                {
                    string value = abbrev[s];


                    merge = string.Join(" ", value);
                }

                    if (!abbrev.ContainsKey(s))
                    {
                        string not = s;
                        merge = string.Join(" ", not);
                    }

                        ;
                        MessageBox.Show(merge);

                }
```

The problem so far is that the final string is outputted into a text box, but only prints the last word as it overwrites. This is a University assignment, so I'm looking for a push in the correct direction as opposed to an actual answer. Many thanks!

Comment: I don't know for sure but have you tried stepping through the loop with the debugger? I think that everything before it looks correct so the loop is most likely your problem.

Comment: @L.B, that wouldn't add any spaces to the result, though.

Answer (score 2):

`string.Join()` takes a collection of strings, concatenates them together and returns the result. But in your case, the collection contains only one item: `value`, or `not`.

To make your code work, you could use something like:

```
merge = string.Join(" ", merge, value);
```

But because of the way strings work, this will be quite slow, so you should use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: Slow is fine for the moment, so I'll give that a go, and then attempt a 'code'StringBuilder'code' once I've got that to work. Cheers!

Comment: As good as using join is, I think that would go against the whole idea of his assignment.

Comment: @JeffMercado, I don't understand why would that go against the idea of the assignment.

Comment: Ah sorry, programming assignments as I remember them often put a constraint restricting the use of certain methods.  He's doing string concatenation so I would have thought that using `String.Concat()` or `String.Join()` would be out of bounds.  He's already using it in the code so I guess it might be ok for him.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
string not = s;
merge = string.Join(" ", not);
```

You are just joining a single element (the latest) with a space delimiter, thus overwriting what you previously put into `merge`.

If you want to stick with string you need to use `Concat` to append the new word onto the output, though this will be slow as you are recreating the string each time. It will be more efficient to use `StringBuilder` to create the output.

If your assignment requires that you use `Join` to build up the output, then you'll need to replace the target words in the `words` array as you loop over them. However, for that you'll need to use some other looping mechanism than `foreach` as that doesn't let you modify the array you're looping over.

Comment: That's not actually joining a space and `s`, it's using the space as a separator. What you describe would be `String.Concat()`.

Answer (score 0):

Better to User `StringBuilder` Class for such purpose

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx